# My seekbar doesn't work in a BottomSheetDialog

Tags: java, android, checkbox, seekbar

I created a BottomSheetDialog with a checkbox and a SeekBar. I want that if the checkbox is checked, the seekbar can be used. My code works but only if i use setContentView(MyLayout), but that makes the layout appair on screen and i want that it works on the dialog. How can i make it work without that? My code here:
Ps: I am sorry for my english, but it isn't my first language.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar=findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setOverflowIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_more_vert_24));


    ImageButton menu_filtri = findViewById(R.id.button_filtri);
    menu_filtri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this,R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
            View BottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet,(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_container));

            bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(BottomSheetView);
            bottomSheetDialog.show();
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet);

            range_distanza = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.next_checkbox);
            seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.range_seekbar);
            set_seekbar();

        }
    });



}

public void set_seekbar() {
    range_distanza.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean ischecked) {
            seekbar.setEnabled(ischecked);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Kotlin:** Use the below code for return value after you seek the bar.

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new AppCompatSeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                       // Your logic
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
    
                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        
                    }
                });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i don't want to return a value , i want the SeekBar to be "frozen" unless the user check the checkbox.  My code is working but not in the bottomSheetDialog, and i don't know how to fix it. Btw, im using java.

Comment: Okay got it, debug and let me know what the value your getting in isChecked